# R Shiny icons disappearing when awesome markers added to leaflet

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, font-awesome, shinydashboard

I am using awesome markers with leaflet in a dashboard shiny app.
There is a funny behaviour that must be due to some interaction between packages, but I don't manage to figure out which nor what a work-around could be:

when the app loads, the tab icons from Font Awesome are rendering correctly. However, once the awesome markers are loaded the tab icons disappear.

Here I include two snapshots of the behaviour, a reproducible example (you may need to adjust the number of points to create sufficient delay), and my session info:

[image]

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(sf)
library(sp)

points <- tibble(ID=c(1:2000),
                 Lat=53+runif(2000, 0, 1),
                 Lon=runif(2000, 0, 1))

points %<>%
    st_as_sf(coords=c('Lon', 'Lat'), crs=4326)

# Define UI
ui <- dashboardPage(

    dashboardHeader(title = "App"),

    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("Map", tabName = "Map", icon = icon("map-marked-alt", lib="font-awesome")),
            menuItem("Other tab", tabName = "Other", icon = icon("volume-up", lib="font-awesome")),
            menuItem("Third tab", tabName = "Third", icon = icon("file-medical-alt", lib="font-awesome"))
        )
    ),

    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            tabItem(
                tabName = "Map",
                # Map box
                boxPlus(width=12,
                        height=800,
                        status='warning',
                        withSpinner(leafletOutput("Network", height = 750))
                        )
                )
            )
        )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    # Calculate bounding box
    bb <- reactive({
        points %>%
            as(., 'Spatial') %>%
            .@bbox %>%
            unname
    })

    # Map
    output$Network <- renderLeaflet({

        Icon <- awesomeIcons(icon = 'circle', iconColor = 'black', library = 'fa', markerColor = 'lightgreen')
        leaflet(options = providerTileOptions(minZoom = 1, maxZoom = 32)) %>%
            addTiles() %>% 
            addAwesomeMarkers(data=points, icon=Icon, label=~ID, layerId=~ID) %>%
            fitBounds(lng1=bb()[1,1], lat1=bb()[2,1], lng2=bb()[1,2], lat2=bb()[2,2])
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

As you can see, it does not happen to all icons.
Also, the icons don't disappear if I use normal markers.

Any idea? Thank you!!

Comment: Do you know which packages from tidyverse you are really using? When I have time I like to try things, but I do not have all of tidyverse loaded, and won't go through the try-search-install-tryagain method of finding missing packages.

Comment: apparently, the problem comes from ```icon=Icon``` in ```addAwesomeMarkers```. If you remove it, the icons in the sidebar stay. It is maybe a bug?

Comment: The icon=Icon in addAwesomeMarkers is needed to show the icon in the marker (in this case a circle, but in the app I'm developing these may be other icons). I will add an issue on the leaflet github too...

Comment: You might want to file an issue [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues). The package had [similar problems](https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/297) some time ago.

Comment: Thank you! I have now posted a git issue both in leaflet and dashboard. I also verified that the problem does not occur using a different library for awesome markers' icons (e.g. glyphicons) so it is a clash due to font awesome.

Comment: Hi did you resolve this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: not solved yet, I just used glyphicons for the map